# COUNT and MAX/MIN and (HAVING?) in one query/ AdventureWorks2017 task

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I have a training task in AdventureWorks2017 DB. The task is the following:
I need a list of the Jobtitle in which the fewest and most women work in proportions. Only consider those in which at least 4 people work.

So far my code looks like this:

```
select a.JobTitle, AVG(ertek) as avg_women, COUNT(*) as sum_women
from
(select BusinessEntityID, JobTitle, Gender, CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0
END as ertek
from HumanResources.Employee) a
group by a.JobTitle
```

This gives me back all the JobTitles, the avarage of women in those titles and the sum of the women in the jobtitles. The problem is that I cant use MAX and MIN in the query (Maybe I need to create another subquery?). And I need to get the last part of the task "Only consider those in which at least 4 people work."
Thanks for the help!

ER diagram: [https://homel.vsb.cz/~dan11/ddj/AdventureWorks2008_db_diagram.pdf](https://homel.vsb.cz/%7Edan11/ddj/AdventureWorks2008_db_diagram.pdf)

Comment: There is nothing in your problem description that suggests the use of AVG() is needed. To the contrary, you need MIN() and MAX() as those correspond to _the fewest and most women_.  And _Only consider those in which at least 4_ seems to imply the use of HAVING. So try again with those clues. 2

Comment: Consider a subquery.  Select sub.JobTitle, sub.avg_women, sum_women ... FROM (select a.JobTitle, AVG(a.ertek) AS avg_women, COUNT(*) AS sum_women, CASE WHEN ... FROM HumanResources.Employee A) AS sub

Comment: @SMor I need to use the avg function because the query needs to give back those job title where the women employee avg is the minimum and the maximum.

Comment: @Dennis could you please be more specific regarding the subquery? there is an inner query already in my query (named "a") Do I need to put everything in one query and create another?

Comment: @MrWolf - looks like you've gotten a pretty solid answer with a lot of detail.  Probably best to follow that path, and see where it leads you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take these kind of requirements one at a time and build your solution gradually.

*Run your query after each additional step to confirm the expected result!*

**Steps**

1. Only job titles with more than 4 people:
   `group by e.JobTitle having count(1) >= 4`
2. Count women proportionally (I interpret this as "the *relative* number of women within one job title"). This requires the overall count and the women only count:
   `count(1) as JobTitleCount` and
   `count(case when e.Gender = 'F' then 1 end) as FemaleCount`
   The relative (proportional) number or percentage then becomes:
   `count(case when e.Gender = 'F' then 1 end)*100.0/count(1) as FemalePercentage`
3. "Fewest" and "most" means [ranking functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql) with an `order by` clause:
   `dense_rank() over(order by`  <percentage from step 2 comes here> `) as RankLeast` and
   `dense_rank() over(order by`  <percentage from step 2 comes here> `desc) as RankMost`
4. Filter on the job titles that are in first place for either ranking:
   `where jfpr.RankLeast = 1 or jfpr.RankMost = 1`

**Intermediate result**

Steps 1. to 3.

```
select  e.JobTitle,
        count(1) as JobTitleCount,
        count(case when e.Gender = 'F' then 1 end) as FemaleCount,
        count(case when e.Gender = 'F' then 1 end)*100.0/count(1) as FemalePercentage,
        dense_rank() over(order by count(case when e.Gender = 'F' then 1 end)*100.0/count(1)     ) as FemalePercentageRankLeast,
        dense_rank() over(order by count(case when e.Gender = 'F' then 1 end)*100.0/count(1) desc) as FemalePercentageRankMost
from HumanResources.Employee e
group by e.JobTitle
having count(1) >= 4
order by FemalePercentage;
```

**Full solution**

Moving the entire previous query in a subquery `jfpr` and leaving out the columns we no longer need for the final result (`JobTitleCount` and `FemaleCount`). The `order by` moves to outside the subquery.

```
select  jfpr.JobTitle,
        jfpr.FemalePercentage
from (  select  e.JobTitle,
                count(case when e.Gender = 'F' then 1 end)*100.0/count(1) as FemalePercentage,
                dense_rank() over(order by count(case when e.Gender = 'F' then 1 end)*100.0/count(1)     ) as FemalePercentageRankLeast,
                dense_rank() over(order by count(case when e.Gender = 'F' then 1 end)*100.0/count(1) desc) as FemalePercentageRankMost
        from HumanResources.Employee e
        group by e.JobTitle
        having count(1) >= 4 ) jfpr -- job female percentage rank
where jfpr.FemalePercentageRankLeast = 1
   or jfpr.FemalePercentageRankMost = 1
order by jfpr.FemalePercentage;
```

**Result**

On my copy of AdventureWorks (no idea what version I have right now) this produces:

```
JobTitle                      FemalePercentage
----------------------------  ----------------
Quality Assurance Technician   0.000000000000
Scheduling Assistant           0.000000000000
Janitor                       50.000000000000
Application Specialist        50.000000000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation it works well!